# Response variable is right skewed

Tags: predictive-models

I'm doing a project where in I came across my response variable to be rightly skewed. If I run the linear regression model or MARS it gives me Rsq as 1. I don't know why is it showing and also doesn't show significant predictors.
Do I need to log transform or box cox transform the data or just the response variable? Or is there any other method to deal this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you think there is with the response being right skew; it may not be relevant to anything (though it might; it's impossible to tell). Skewness of the marginal distribution of the response doesn't relate to any regression assumption; the conditional distribution may be relevant to some things you might want to do. The issue with $R^2=1$ but no significant predictors sounds like muticollinearity may be a problem but that's a separate issue. It's not possible to say much without more details. Many questions on site relate to each of the issues you appear to be raising.

Comment: How many observations and predictor variables do you have?

Comment: Sorry for not having it clear. I'll try to explain further. I survey data set where in I converted the data into frequency data to have a continuous variables from categorical. Initially I had 0.4 million rows and 100 variables, now I have 1114 rows and 48 observation after pre processing according to state, year and one of the variable to be categorical with level 4 . If I see my response variable on histogram it comes out to be right skewed. I ran a linear regression model with that response variable, I'm getting Rsq = 1

Comment: And if i see the correlation plot I have almost all the variables correlated to each other @Glen_b

Comment: "I have 1114 rows and 48 observation"  do you mean variables rather than observations? normally it would be one row per observation, one column per variable. The fact that a histogram of the response variable looks right skew can be completely irrelevant -- no regression assumption relates to the distribution of the marginal distribution of the response (i.e. to the thing you're looking at); unfortunately many basic books get this wrong.

Comment: Yes 48 variables. okay and when I checked the correlation of the variables almost all the variable were correlated to each other which gave me Rsq value to be 1 for Lm and MARS model. I cannot remove variables as they are taken from survey data where in the options of the question asked are made into variables so as to get the data from categorical to frequency data by doing that. @Glen_b. I'm stuck with this survey data set.